# TikZ: Having circle borders only grown to the outside

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-shape

How do I let circle borders only grow to the outside?
If I write

```
\node[circle, draw, minimum size=2cm, line width=4mm] {};
```

Then the inside of the circle has a diameter of 16mm, since 2mm of the 4mm grow inside the 2cm and 2mm of the 4mm grow outside of the 2cm. How do I get the circle to only grow to the outside? The trivial answer would be

```
\node[circle, draw, minimum size=2cm+4mm, line width=4mm] {};
```

Is there a better way of doing it? (Meaning a command that is intended for this?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can define a simple style to do the job:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5]{standalone}

\tikzset{
  inner size/.style={minimum size=#1+\pgflinewidth,inner sep=0sp},
  outer size/.style={minimum size=#1-\pgflinewidth,inner sep=0sp},
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\node[circle, draw,   outer size=1cm, line width=2mm, red] {};
\node[circle, draw,   inner size=1cm, line width=2mm, blue] {};
\node[circle, draw, minimum size=1cm, line width=.2mm, dashed] {};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: boink]

Setting `inner sep` to nil isn't necessary unless you put content into nodes.

Comment: I do put content into the nodes, so thanks. Though it isn't as canon as if there was a tikz command, but its definitely better than my hack.